# Criando uma calculadora por Rotação Polonesa Inversa em C

Tags: c, stack

preciso fazer para um exercício uma calculadora RPN só para os casos (+ - / * ), por meio de pilhas, é necessário que a entrada seja do tipo `ABC+*`, que o programa entenda isso, o usuario de os valores de A,B e C, e, por meio do sistema de pilhas, calcule o resultado da conta, até agora tenho isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXTAM 51

typedef struct {
  char Item[MAXTAM];
  int Topo;
} TPilha;

void TPilha_Iniciar (TPilha *p) {
  p->Topo = -1;
}

int TPilha_Vazia (TPilha *p) {
  if (p->Topo == -1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int TPilha_Inserir (TPilha *p, int x) {
  if (p->Topo == MAXTAM){
    return 0;
  } else {
    p->Topo++;
    p->Item[p->Topo] = x;
    return 1;
  }
}

float TPilha_Remover (TPilha *p) {
  int aux;
  if (TPilha_Vazia(p) == 1 ) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    aux = p->Item[p->Topo];
    p->Topo--;
    return 1;
  }
}

int main() {
  int count = 0;
  char arranjo[MAXTAM];
  scanf("%s", arranjo);
  int tamanho = strlen(arranjo);
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<=tamanho;i++) {
    if(isalpha(arranjo[i])){
      count++;
    }
  }
  float arranjov[count];
  for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
    scanf("%f", &arranjov[i]);
  }
 return 0; 
}
```

Como dá para ver, ja consegui criar o sistema de pilhas, o scan da string do tipo `ABC+*`e o scan dos valores que o usuario deseja atribuir para A, B e C. O problema surge agora, como posso fazer o processo de empilhar/desempilhar no sistema de Notação Polonesa Inversa? Eu pensei em usar `switch()`com cada caso de + * - /, porém não sei como conciliar isso com as pilhas. Desde já obrigado.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_calculator_algorithm#C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é um algoritmo que já tenha tendo, mas isso se encaixa nos compiladores. Já tentou usar algo semelhante ao shift reduce, vai empilhando os números até achar um token de sinal (-+*/) desempilha com a operação aritmética usando o switch e no laço, vai fazendo a medida que encontra os sinais matematicos.

```
4 8 9 + -

empilhar 4
empilhar 4 8
empilhar 4 8 9
empilhar 4 8 9 +
calcular 4 (8+9)
reduzir  4 17
empilhar 4 17 -
calcular 4 - 17
retornar 13 (if novo token == 0, final de string, \n)
```

Veja se isso ajuda.

Comment: Da para brincar legal ai, um desafio bem interessante.